# Implementing Open CV in QTCreator on Raspberry Pi

Tags: opencv, raspberry-pi, qtonpi

I try to record a video with my USB Webcam in a QT GUI Application on my Raspberry Pi.
All tutoriuals I can find focus on cross-compiling. I want to program and build this directly on the Pi. I've succesfully installed QT Creator and build GUI Applications, they're working.

Questions:

- Is it possible to implement OpenCV into the RaspberryPi QT Creator? If yes, how?
- Is this the correct approach to solve the problem?
- Is there a better way to record videos with a QT GUI Application beside Open CV?

Thank you very much!

Comment: opencv will take ~2gb disk space while building. also, if all you need is recording video, opencv might be way too heavy. (plugging into ffmeg, gstreamer might be more adequate)

Comment: Yeah - I thought about that, too. Is it possible to use ffmpeg in QT? Do you have any example or tutorial about implementing? I think I've already installed ffmpeg to test the webcam (streamed it to the browser)

Comment: sorry, no idea (not into Qt at all).